# catalog_product_collection_load_after - identify the "right" collection

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer, product-list, product-collection

I want to do some processing on the products list (the products shown when browsing categories etc) before they are rendered.

I tried using the **catalog_product_collection_load_after** event, but its called on any products collection used, which include things like recently viewed items, related items, etc. and I only want to react on the time its called for the actual main products list.

I tried to filter the events by checking things like block type/name, controller name, page category etc, but they all proved to be insufficient to distinguish between the event on the main product list and other spam.

**so my question:**

1. how can I edit the products list before they are shown via events (eg **without** editing Magento core code / temlates)?
2. if your answer is "observe the catalog_product_collection_load_after event": how do I know which of the many product collections loaded is the main products grid?

thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the event `catalog_block_product_list_collection`.
This one is dispatched in the [product list block](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/List.php#L162).